# Change URL from recover username / password in joomla

Tags: email, joomla, passwords, recover

I need to change the URL from recover username / recover password email of my Joomla's website.

The email in `en-GB.com_users.ini` is:

> COM_USERS_EMAIL_PASSWORD_RESET_BODY="Hello,\n\nA request has been made
>   to reset your %s account password. To reset your password, you will
>   need to submit this verification code in order to verify that the
>   request was legitimate.\n\nThe verification code is %s\n\nSelect the
>   URL below and proceed with resetting your password.\n\n %s \n\nThank
>   you.

The URL I got in email is `https://url.com/en/logout?view=reset&layout=confirm&token=c602b0c60d10424f1b08cab860fea53f`

I need change the logout URL in email to *correct* link, because this way every time the user is going to homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Root-->components-->com_users-->models-->reset.php

```
function processResetRequest(){
   Find $data['link_text'] = JRoute::_($link, false, $mode);

   Replace $data['link_text'] = JURI::Root().$link;

{

thr url become www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_users&view=reset&layout=confirm&token=zfcsdsd
```

Comment: Thanks !!! This change works. But now I tryied to recover password and I got redirected to home, I think its form redirect to logout too.

Comment: The link works perfect, I mean when I send the form, I dont get a recover password page, I got redirect to homepage.

Comment: Can you check https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/how-to-recover-a-lost-joomla-username-and-password/